# Instantiation of template static member variable

Tags: c++, templates

I’m trying to puzzle out how clang determines what C++ template static member variables require instantiation, and I’m seeing some behavior that has me confused.

Given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo>

int report(const char *name)
{
    printf("Reporting class: %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}

template<typename ReportedClass>
class reported_class
{
public:
    reported_class()
    {
        _reported_instances++;
    }

private:
    static int _reported_instances;
};

template<typename ReportedClass>
int reported_class<ReportedClass>::_reported_instances = report(typeid(ReportedClass).name());

class foo : reported_class<foo>
{
public:
    int baz() { return 0; }

};

class bar : reported_class<bar>
{
public:
    bar() { }
    int baz() { return 0; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I see the following:

```
$ c++ -v
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.0.68) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
$ c++ test.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
Reporting class: 3bar
$
```

Why is the static for reported_class being instantiated, but not the one for foo? The only difference appears to be the presence of a constructor, but I’d expect the reported_class constructor to be called in either case (therefore forcing static instantiation due to use in the constructor). Is there a reason for this in the standard that I’m not aware of, and is this something that can be relied upon?

gcc-4.7.3 displays the same behavior, so I assume that this is something that I"m misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in the not shown `main` function you're not instantiating either class.

Then there's no reason for the compiler to generate a default constructor for class `foo`.

And without that, there's no code that instantiates `reported_class<foo>`.

Comment: Added the main() function, which, as you surmised, instantiates neither class. Your explanation sounds plausible, but in that case, can the instantiation of reported_class<bar> be relied upon, or is the compiler free to optimize it away entirely in the absence of any construction of the object?

Comment: @kihlasht: I would think not because the standard generally goes to pains to preserve well-defined side effects, e.g. not allowing an unused variable to be optimized away if its constructor or destructor can have side effect. But I don't *know*. So I suggest you ask this as a new question, if it matters (but personally I would rather make sure that things happen as I want, rather than rely on a subtlety that one has to ask experts about in the hope that one of them may know or take the time to research and analyze, and which some compilers then by murphy's law are sure to handle incorrectly).